# Gradle - How to Map a drive?

Tags: java, gradle, ant, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I want to map a drive from gradle task.I know how to do it from ant but can someone let me know how could I convert that ant task into gradle and map a drive 
on windows server.Below is my ant task to map a drive and delete the map drive

```
<target name="createmap">
    <property name="user231" value="${deployip}\${deployuser}"/>
    <exec executable="cmd.exe">
        <arg line="/c if not exist ${mapdir} net use ${mapdir} \\${deployip}\Sites ${deploypw} /USER:${user231}"/>
    </exec>
</target>
<target name="deletemap">
    <exec executable="cmd.exe">
        <arg line="/c if exist ${mapdir} net use ${mapdir} /delete"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're effectively running commands windows command line, you can do this in a gradle task of type `Exec`. See here for example: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html

Answer (score 0):

I used the below code and it is working fine

```
task drivemap(type:Exec) {

  //on windows:
  commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'net use z: /delete'
  commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'NET USE Z: \\x.x.x.x\ZDrive\Clinprod  %megpass% /USER:TSH\%meguser%'
  commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'Z:'
  commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'xcopy /Y Z:\Episodes\Development\Meg%version%\drop\Build%buildNumber% D:\MegDS\release /e/s' 

  //store the output instead of printing to the console:
  standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

  //extension method drivemap.output() can be used to obtain the output:
  ext.output = {
    return standardOutput.toString()
  }
```

}